# Verify the quality of the video that was called by the URI, that is, if the video quality is higher than 360 pixels, it is converted to 360, then

Tags: android, android-studio

Verify the quality of the video that was called by the URI, that is, if the video quality is higher than 360 pixels, it is converted to 360, then extract the URI of the new video Android Studio
I see for the original video =urit;
I see for the new video =uritt;
I need help with the whole code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.